# How to open Jquery dilogbox middle of the screen in frame environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dialog

I have 3 frames in screen , using frameset I did like this.

index.thml

```
<frameset rows="75%,25%">
    <frameset cols="20%,80%">
        <frame src="TreeGroup.jsp" name="left" id="f1"/>
        <frame src="DisplayMap.jsp"   name="top" id="f2"/>
    </frameset>
    <frame src="Tabs.jsp" name="bottom"/>
 </frameset>
```

in frame `f1` there is a Javascript method `Add_Group()` to open a dilogbox. When I click on a link I call `Add_Group()`. The problem I am facing is the dilog is openning in frame `f1` so it is not visible properly. How to open dilog to center of the screen.

My javascript function is,

```
function Add_Group()
{
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
}
```

Html for dilog is ,

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
 <p>Enter group Nmae</p>
 <input type="text" name="grpName">
```

Comment: Best solution is stop using frames , they are deprecated

Comment: Oh . . , how to convert it to `<iframe>` . The project already developed. I felt very hard to convert it to <iframe>

Comment: Most people would put the tabs, tree and map in same window these days. Using nested windows (frames) you will have to communicate up to `window.top` to do what you want

Comment: can I have any example links

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top

Comment: thank you , but I am asking any examples on iframe.